# Linux yum Commands that are Equivalent to these Ubuntu apt-get Commands

Tags: command-line, apt, yum, apache-httpd, amazon-ec2

I'm using an AWS EC2 instance and I'm trying to switch from an Ubuntu instance to a Linux (Amazon Linux AMI) instance and in doing so I need to figure out the equivalent `apt-get` to `yum` commands and packages to install.

In essence how would you translate the following from `apt-get` to `yum`?

*Side note assume I have already assume the* `root user` *role via* `sudo su`*, which is why `sudo` is not used in conjunction with the following commands.*

`apt-get` commands:

- `apt-get update` (Assuming this would be equivalent to `yum update -y`
- `apt-get upgrade -y`
- `apt-get dist-upgrade -y`
- `apt-get autoremove -y`
- `apt-get install apache2 php5 php5-cli php5-fpm php5-gd libssh2-php libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt php5-mysql git unzip zip postfix php5-curl mailutils php5-json -y`
- `a2enmod rewrite headers`
- `php5enmod mcrypt`

Comment: There is thios wonderful page on the archwiki, the [`pacman rosetta`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=Pacman/Rosetta&oldid=404154). Since yum has been decommissioned in favor of `dnf`, the `yum` commands are not present anymore. I just linked to the most recent version containing the `yum` commands.

Comment: Hey @joepd thanks for the resource that was a very useful bit of information. My question though is do I just replace `apt-get` with `yum`? I was under the impression that the packages for each package manager `yum` v. `apt-get` are different, ex. I typically install apache on linux via `yum install httpd24` whereas in the above Ubuntu example it's using the `apache2` package.

Comment: How are `a2enmod` and `php5enmod` relevant to your question? They aren't `apt-get` commands therefore won't have an equivalent `yum` command.

Comment: @garethTheRed I completely understand your question and I apologize for including something that may seem a bit off topic considering the title. I'm new to the server side of things and I'm following a tutorial where the instructor created an Ubuntu instance using an AWS EC2 instance using the above listed configurations and since I'd prefer to use a Linux box, I wanted to figure out how I could configure my Linux EC2 instance with the same (or similar) setup that they configured their Ubuntu instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various distros name their packages slightly differently and there is no automated way to map one to the other.  You've probably quoted the best example already with Apache, which is `apache2` on Debian/Ubuntu systems and `httpd` on CentOS/RedHat/Fedora systems, `apache` on Arch, `apache2` on openSuse, `www-servers/apache` on Gentoo etc.

The best way to find the packages is to search for them with `yum search`:

```
yum search apache
...
httpd.x86_64 : Apache HTTP Server
...
```

Which finds that Apache in the description.  You'll get about 200 lines of packages here, so maybe pipe it into `less` to read or into `grep` to look for keywords.

If you know the file name and want to find the package which provides this, then run `yum provides`:

```
yum provides *bin/httpd
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.simwood.com
 * epel: epel.mirrors.ovh.net
 * extras: mirror.simwood.com
 * updates: mirror.mhd.uk.as44574.net
httpd-2.4.6-40.el7.centos.x86_64 : Apache HTTP Server
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/sbin/httpd


httpd-2.4.6-40.el7.centos.x86_64 : Apache HTTP Server
Repo        : @base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/sbin/httpd
```

Simply running `yum provides httpd` will list any package that has files which end in httpd, not just the executable, so it's best to narrow the search by prefixing it with `*bin/`.

Google can also help you find common packages.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. The Ubuntu setup thats listed in my question is used to setup an AWS Ubuntu instance. That said – and this may seem obvious but I'm new to this so please forgive my ignorance – 1) could I setup my AWS Linux EC2 instance like the Ubuntu instance by simple creating a AMP stack within my Linux system? and 2) if this is true do I need to do anything in my Linux instance to replicate the following Ubuntu commands: `a2enmod rewrite headers` or `php5enmod mcrypt` or is `mod_rewrite` and `mcrypt` (when it's installed) automatically enabled in a LAMP stack?

Comment: @Corey - Amazon AMI is based on RedHat/CentOS 5 and 6 I believe.  Therefore, your best bet would be to look for LAMP tutorials for one of those platforms.  If they're not a 100% match for AMI they'll be much closer than Ubuntu/Debian tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll begin steering my learning in the direction you suggested. Cheers.